# use JSOM to get all fields and views in a list

Tags: 2010, list, list-view, jsom, schema

I know how to make multiple/different calls to get details about all the fields and views in a list but I was wondering if there is a way to do it with one call.

I know I can use `get_fields()` and `get_views()` to get the fields/views but then I have to iterate them and make a 2nd call to load all the details.

I figured I can use `get_schemaXml()` to get the list schema but that doesn't include all the views and their schema.

```
function doIt()
{
    var clientContext;
    var oWebsite;
    var oList;
    var schema;

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("Announcements");

    clientContext.load(this.oList, "SchemaXml");

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
        Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
    );

    function successHandler(sender, args) {
        console.log(this.oList.get_schemaXml());
    }

    function errorHandler(sender, args) {
        console.log(args);
    }
}

doIt()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the method that I use. It uses AJAX and ODATA. It will give you the properties of both the fields and the views. You would just iterate over them afterwards. I can include more details latter.

```
var myFilter = 'lists/GetByTitle(\'Site Assets\')?$select=Fields,Views&$expand=Fields,Views',
    jax = $.ajax(get_SPFolderBaseData('webAbsoluteUrl', myFilter));

$.when(jax).then(dataInspec).fail(oops);

function dataInspec(d){
            var data = d.d;

            console.log('Data Inspec... ', d, ' just data... ', data);
        }

function get_SPData(root, url){
            return {
                url: _spPageContextInfo[root]+ '/_api/' + url,
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                    'x-RequestDigest': $('#_REQUESTDIGEST').val()
                }
            }
        }

function oops( sender, args) {
            var errObj = JSON.parse(sender.responseText),
                errMsg = errObj.error.message.value;

            console.log('Your Request Failed:\n Status: ' + sender.status+ '\n State: ' +sender.readyState+ '\n Status Text: ' +sender.statusText+ '\n Message: ' +errMsg);
        }
```